# How to gve track points for Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-slider

I have a scenario like I have a Bootstrap slider, in that I want track points on the track of the slider and the tool tip must be fixed (i.e. it must be exist even after click).

Here is my Plunker link:

http://embed.plnkr.co/D3GJQn/preview

I need to get points on the track as shown in below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add property `tooltip:"always"` to show the tooltip always

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mySlider = $("#slider-input").slider({
                min:0,
                max: 4200,
                value:1000,
                step:1000,
                tooltip:"always"
            });
        });
```

You can see the complete set of options here - https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#options

To get the current value of slide, see below.

```
     $("#slider-input").on('slide', function (ev) {
        console.log($("#slider-input").val());
      });
```

You can use `ticks: [0, 500, 1000, 1500]`, property to show intermedaite points. for more http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

example - https://plnkr.co/edit/W8c2UuPMiEeMwQ8g7kCV?p=preview

Comment: But,how to get the track points,can you please help me in that

Comment: I updated the question with image,can you please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the current value:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var mySlider = $("#slider-input").slider({
                min:0,
                max: 4200,
                value:1000,
                step:1000,
                formatter:  function(value) {
                       return 'Current value: ' + value;
               }
            });
        });
```

You can also show the value by doing:

```
    $("#mySlider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
           $("#sliderValue").text(slideEvt.value);
     });
```

with HTML:

```
<span>Current Value: <span id="sliderValue">1</span></span>
```

Here is a link to show some examples I found after doing this:
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks,but I need rangeHighlights for every point,can you please help me

Comment: You mean colors on the dots or the lines while sliding?

Comment: Check out the link I posted, it has a lot of examples, one of which may be the actual objective you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Example 13](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/). Here is the example code, take note of the `ticks` property:

```
var slider = new Slider("#ex13", {
    ticks: [0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ticks_labels: ['$0', '$100', '$200', '$300', '$400'],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 30
});
```